# How to add a keypress event listener into my dynamically created input text field in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a `keypress` listener to my input text field. This is my code:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.id="vac";
input.addEventListener("keypress",(e) => {return IsAlphaNumeric(e);});

function IsAlphaNumeric(e) { //prohibits input of all special characters except for `/`
  var specialKeys = new Array();
  specialKeys.push(8);  //Backspace
  specialKeys.push(9);  //Tab
  specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
  specialKeys.push(36); //Home
  specialKeys.push(35); //End
  specialKeys.push(37); //Left
  specialKeys.push(39); //Right
  var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));

  if(e.charCode==47){
      ret=true;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Now when I execute the code, the `keypress` listener is not working. What is wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: `() => IsAlphaNumeric(input.value));` is not passing the event.... `function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {`

Comment: `input.addEventListener("keydown", IsAlphaNumeric);` or `input.addEventListener("keydown",(e) => IsAlphaNumeric(e, input.value));`

Comment: Tried it,still not working

Comment: Your code just calls the function, it returns, but that return is useless since you are not doing anything with it. You probably want to use preventDefault

Comment: `input.addEventListener("keydown",(e) => return IsAlphaNumeric(e));`

Comment: Why you add `input.value` inside the parentheses when you planing to use the argument as the event object just write the function name only without parentheses and remove `() =>`  from the event listener it's

Comment: Tried `input.addEventListener("keypress",(e) => {return IsAlphaNumeric(e);});`. Still not working

Comment: Btw, do not use `new Array();` and `array.push()`, but implicitly instantiate it like `const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];` and if possible, do it outside of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent non alpha-numerical characters, with the exception of `/`, this is the modern way to go. Use `event.preventDefault()`. And a simple RegExp is enough for string testing.

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');

input.type = 'text';
input.id = 'vac';

const shouldPrevent = (str) => !/[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF\d\/]/.test(str);

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (shouldPrevent(e.key) && e.cancelable) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

document.getElementById('root').appendChild(input);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I want to prevent all special characters except for `/`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `keypress`?

Comment: @user15089140 To see the difference between similar keyboard events you can use this [tool](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/d4e/raw-file/tip/key-event-test.html). In this case, `keydown` is to be preferred. `keypress` does not detect `delete` key for example.